# Imagen se muestra al abrir ventana de impresion en html y php

Tags: php, html, web

Con Javascript abro una ventana para imprimir un ticket, esta función recibe  el url del método que contiene la información del ticket en html, en este genero un código de barras, al abrir la ventana de impresión se muestra toda la información del ticket menos el código de barras, pero si abro directamente el método sin la función que abre la ventana para imprimir el código si se muestra, también probé con una imagen local y en las dos formas se ve, solo da el problema con el código de barras, les dejo el código que uso y unas capturas, espero puedan ayudarme se los agradeceré mucho.

```
//CON ESTO ABRO LA VENTANA RECIBE COMO PARAMETRO LA URL DEL METODO DEL TICKET
<script type="text/javascript">

    function printParking(parking_url)
    {   
      $.ajax({
        url: parking_url,
        type: 'get',
        success:function(response) {

          var mywindow = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'height=400,width=600');

          mywindow.document.write(response);
          mywindow.document.close();
          mywindow.focus(); 

          mywindow.print();
          mywindow.close(); 

        }
      })
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#datatables').DataTable({
        'order': []
      });

      $("#parkingSideTree").addClass('active');
      $("#manageParkingSideTree").addClass('active');

    });
  </script>
```

```php
//CON ESTO GENERO EL TICKET
 public function printInvoice($id)
    {
        if(!in_array('viewParking', $this->permission)) {
            redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
        }

        if($id) {
            $parking_data = $this->model_parking->getParkingData($id);
            $company_info = $this->model_company->getCompanyData(1);
            // get the vehicle type 
            $vehicle_category = $this->model_category->getCategoryData($parking_data['vechile_cat_id']);

            $check_in_date = date("Y-m-d", $parking_data['in_time']);
            $check_in = date("h:i a", $parking_data['in_time']);
            $description = $parking_data['description'];


                $check_out_date = date("Y-m-d", $parking_data['out_time']);
                $check_out = date("h:i a", $parking_data['out_time']);
                $total = $parking_data['earned_amount'];
                $html = '<html>
                <head>
                    <title>Imprimir Ticket de Salida</title>
                    <style>
                    .main-content {
                        text-align: center;
                        width: 100%;
                    }

                    table.table {
                        width: 50%;
                        margin: 0 auto;
                        text-align: left;
                    }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div class="main-content">
                        <div class="company-info">
                            <div class="company-name"><p>'.$company_info['name'].'</p></div>
                            <div class="company-address"><p>'.$company_info['address'].'</p></div>
                            <div class="company-address"><p>------------------------------------------------------</p></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="parking-info">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Fecha Entrada: '.$check_in_date.'</td>
                                    <td>Hora Entrada: '.$check_in.'</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Fecha Salida: '.$check_out_date.'</td>
                                    <td>Hora Salida: '.$check_out.'</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Parqueo no: '.$parking_data['parking_code'].' </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Tipo de vehículo: '.ucwords($vehicle_category['name']).' </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Descripción: '.$description.' </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Total a pagar: $'.$total.'.00 </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <p> Para su propia conveniencia, por favor no pierda el ticket. </p>
                            <img alt="testing" src="/parking/barcode?text='.$parking_data['parking_code'].'&size=40&print=true""/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="parking-message">
                            '.$company_info['message'].'
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                </body>
            </html>
            ';              
                echo $html;
}
```

[image: CUANDO DE ABRE LA VENTANA NO SE MUESTRA EL BARCODE]

[image: SI LO LLAMO DIRECTAMENTE SI SE MUESTRA EL BARCODE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solo para descartar**

Prueba habilitar los gráficos en segundo plano.

En la ventana de impresión de Chrome, hay una opción "Más opciones", y dentro la opción "Gráficos en segundo plano". Tal como lo muestra la imágen siguiente:

[image: Más opciones de configuración]

**¿Probaste buscando preguntas similares?**

[Google Chrome - No muestra imágenes en vista previa de impresión (en inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725373/google-chrome-not-showing-image-in-print-preview)

Quedo atento. Por favor publica la solución cuando la tengas.
Saludos

Comment: Hola muchas gracias intenté eso pero sin resultados, lo que noté es que el código si hace bien las cosas probé en todos los demás navegadores que hay y si funciona solo en Chrome no.

Comment: ¿Probaste poniendo la ruta absoluta en vez de la ruta relativa? Es decir una ruta directa a un archivo de imágen y no esto `/parking/barcode?text`.

Comment: si lo probé y sin problema solo da problema con el barcode en chrome.

Comment: Mira este [enlace](https://superuser.com/a/935118), dicen que hay que poner la ruta absoluta sin parámetros a la imágen.

Comment: lo intente pero sigue igual creo que es problema del assistente de impresion de chrome pero de todas maneras muchas gracias Federico :D

Answer (score 0):

Imagino no estas cargando la libreria en el archivo donde se general la respuesta a imprimir , yo hice algo similar y lo tengo con un simple formulario y el archivo que recibe tiene la libreria cargada y ahi es donde se genera el pdf , y si lo queres en forma de popup lo haces simple con jquery .

Comment: Gracias, pero al parecer el problema es del navegador Chrome, probé en otros navegadores edge, Firefox, e internet explorer y si se muestra el código de barras en la ventana de impresión